# Can React-Redux do without react-saga or react-thunk framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

Is it a best practice to use react-redux without a saga or thunk middleware?

I have a react-redux application but it don't have any of these middlewares. This is the code that I have right now.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import allReducers from './app/reducers/index';
import Header from './app/components/header';
import './index.css';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(allReducers, {}, applyMiddleware(logger));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Header />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: "Is it a best practice to use react-redux without a saga or thunk middleware?" Where do you get this recommendation?

Comment: And just to be clear react-redux provides a link between a `store` object you are passing to a `Provider` and wrapped component props. It should not care about middlewares at all.

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems like almost everyone is using either of this libraries to handly async actions in redux, it is totally possible to manage without, simply by writing your own redux middleware. There are a few things to keep in mind, but apart from that it is deadly simple.

An example of what it looks like

```
/**
 * Auth middleware
 */
export const authMiddleware: Middleware = <State>({ getState, dispatch }) => next => action => {

  if (isType(action, actions.authExpired)) {

    refreshToken()
      .then(token => {
        setSession(token, true);
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Silent auth error', e));

  }

  return next(action);

}
```

Documentation on writing middleware
https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html